# Why i am getting DeadlineExceededException: in my web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, exception, servlets

I am using google app engine. Before everything was working fine but now when i call a servlet, browser takes a lot of time and then shows this:

```
 DeleteBooksServlet: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (0000000000000000) started at 2011/10/08 10:58:13.573 UTC and was still executing at 2011/10/08 10:59:13.036 UTC.
```

In that servlet i have a query which takes all books from database and then delete them.

Before same servlet was working fine but now i am getting this. Why i am getting this thing now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: More than 1 minute? Are you deleting >10 million books or something? Or are you deleting with a `WHERE` on a non-indexed column? Read on about how and when to properly index DB tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you certainly have so many books in the database that the query takes a lot of time (more than 1 minute), and that GAE throws this exception when a request is so long.

See http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Quotas_and_Limits

Answer (score 2):

Deleting n books takes O(n) time. When that time passes the request limit, you need to make that operation faster.

A very good general technique is to break the deletes into batches, where a batch may delete, say, 100 books). Then use the task queue framework to schedule and run the batches. Some people take this further, and use the [MapReduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) framework to managing the batching.